# New to Programming (Python)

Tags: python

I have just started trying to learn Python (windows) via online guides/courses etc (I read that this was a good language to start in). I was just wondering if there are any specific texts you would advise to aid me. As I said in the title I am a complete beginner in programming so any help would be great.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Not really on topic (read [ask] and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)). Look on Amazon. Read some samples and customer reviews. Pick one that matches your needs. Books from either O'Reilly or No-Starch Press tend to be good.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My greatest advice for new developers is to be efficient at learning and be headed in the right direction. Most of the people drive straight into learning the language and remembering syntax and all kinds of aspects about the language, instead of actually doing any programming. While it's essential to know the fundamentals of a language to do any projects, it also can be wasteful in terms of productivity.

So, to say this shortly, learn the core fundamentals and immediately start creating projects that you always wanted to make. No matter how hard your end goal is going to be you just need to split into parts that you will be able to compete and learn on the way of making it.

To say it even more shortly, learn how to drive the car, not the car itself